# Exponential number formatting PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, format

I have a column called **card_number** (table = customer) and the entries are displayed exponentially, like the entries listed below:

4.56E+15

4.54E+15

4.56E+15

5.39E+15

4.49E+15

Can someone help me formatting every entry of the column to a 16 digit entry? (Still has to be datatype varchar)

I'd be very thankful if someone could help me with this...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If your existing data type is varchar, seems to be data is inserted as it is into the table. Can help you if the data type is numeric

Comment: can you help me how this needs to be done if data type is numeric?

Answer (score 4):

Please use below type casting while selecting the column,

```
select card_number::decimal(38,0) from customer;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result as string, that could be

```
to_char(CAST(card_number AS numeric), '999999999999999999999999999FM')
```

Comment: @Jan There is probably a question lurking somewhere in that rant, but you made it too hard to discern it.

Comment: I am sorry for the rant and will leave it at that. The question is whether there is an easy way (maybe a type such as 'scientific' alongside 'numeric') to format double precision numbers with mantissa at some fixed number of decimals and an exponent.
I wrote a plpsql function to do that, and it works, but I would not call it fantastic, so I'm not sharing it at this point. But, perhaps I'm missing something afterall?

Comment: @Jan Now I get it, thanks. You can format a number in scientific notation with `to_char(numcol, '9.9999EEEE')`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did not get that, so I owe another apology for believing it was hard in the first place - as a C++ programmer doing postgres on the side without structured learning...